# pandas DataFrame incorrect ranking

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with two rows, which I'm trying to rank. One of the two rows is ranked properly but the other is not:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
                   ['47', '196', '82', '-7', '72', '-38', '27', '53', '103', '25', '-61', '-41', '59', '-11'], 
                   ['324', '304', '296', '274', '264', '249', '227', '226', '213', '199', '196', '177', '174', '157']
                  ])

print df 
print df.rank(ascending=False, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
 0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13
 0   47  196   82   -7   72  -38   27   53  103   25  -61  -41   59  -11
 1  324  304  296  274  264  249  227  226  213  199  196  177  174  157


 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13
 0   5   8   1  10   2  13   6   4   9   7  11  12   3  14
 1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14
```

Row-1 is properly ranked highest to lowest, but row-0 is clearly not. Am I misunderstanding pandas rank method, or am I doing something incorrectly? Many thanks

Edit: My values were strings instead of ints, hence the incorrect rankings. Problem solved, thanks all

Answer (score 2):

It might be because you are using str declaration instead of int. Try this,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([ [47, 196, 82, -7, 72, -38, 27, 53, 103, 25,-61, -41, 59, -11], 
                   [324, 304, 296, 274, 264, 249, 227, 226, 213, 199, 196, 177, 174, 157]])
print (df )
print (df.rank(ascending=False, axis=1))
```

This will yield,

```
    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11   12   13
0   47  196   82   -7   72  -38   27   53  103   25  -61  -41   59  -11
1  324  304  296  274  264  249  227  226  213  199  196  177  174  157

[2 rows x 14 columns]
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13
0   7   1   3  10   4  12   8   6   2   9  14  13   5  11
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14

[2 rows x 14 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

D'oh. My values are strings instead of ints...